# GCP - Auto Remove Old GCR Images

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, sh

How to implement
GCP - Auto Remove Old GCR Images?

This is the reference i found but if any proper solutions for that so it would be great for me!
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcr-cleaner

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [`gcloud container images delete`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/delete) could help to delete existing images

> Deletes the image as long as there aren't additional, unspecified tags referencing it:

> `gcloud container images delete <IMAGE_NAME>`

To retrieve the image name that is to be deleted through [`gcloud container images list-tags`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list-tags)

Comment: We need to create build.sh file or golang file (if we are working on any language). ? @zangw

Comment: You could run `gcloud container` shell command through [exec.Command](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec) @VIKASKATARIYA