# GCP - Remove Obsolete Buckets

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

GCP - Remove Obsolete Buckets

Remove Obsolete Buckets in GCP in golang
How can I implement this thing in golang ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to delete the bucket through [BucketHandle.Delete](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage#BucketHandle.Delete)

```golang
import (
    "context"

    "cloud.google.com/go/storage"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error.
    }
    if err := client.Bucket("my-bucket").Delete(ctx); err != nil {
        // TODO: handle error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me to solve another one( i mean give some idea or solutions ) for GCP
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74054166/gcp-auto-remove-old-gcr-images 

@zangw